# Create Presigned URL Expires after one week?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using aws s3 bucket and the presigned url expires after one week

Actually The photo url is expired after one week and no one can access it after that so for example i have a post and this post has photo url assign to it so how the front end can access that url if it's gonna be expired in the future ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum S3 presigned url validity is 1 week, this is by design, you can't change it.

But what you can do is either:

1. If you want to make photos publicly available, you can create public S3 bucket and when uploading images to there specify public read ACL.
   Then your photos will be forever reachable at `http[s]://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/photo.ext`
2. Or you can create an endpoint at your Backend server to generate new presigned urls.
   So that browser first makes request to get photo urls from Backend.
   And then display them.